# HLOOK UP SUM with look value refence in text

Tags: excel, vba

i want sum with h lookup more than 20 rows without type  ,{2,5,9},0))   in the functions  because i have more  rows but my  look value is reference and is text
`=SUM(HLOOKUP(LookupValue,A1:C10,{2,5,9,10 ,11,12 ,13,,,,101,102},0))
  but the values are numbers

Comment: Why not use `sumif`?

Comment: Can you put some sample data and expected output?

Comment: OK, you don't want to type **{2, 5, 9}**. How are you going to put rows 2, 5 and 9 into the formula?

Comment: because are more than 3 rows.............. i cant put 12345676,,,,101,,,,1001

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add up rows 2, 5 and 9 in the table try this:
type 2, 5 and 9 in "some_range"
Then:
    `=SUM(HLOOKUP(4,$A$1:$C$10,some_range,0))`
But save the formula as an array formula: press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of just enter